# Oracle SQL FETCH NEXT Across Several Rows

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-fetch

I have a SQL statement that fetches the next 20 rows from a table.  There's a field in the table called SERIES_ID which contains values that might be shared by several rows in the table, e.g.:

```
MY_TABLE
PRIMARY_KEY |  TEXT_FIELD | SERIES_ID
===================================
1           | sdfdsfdsfds |    1001
2           | sdafsdfdf   |    1002
3           | sdffghhjhj  |    1002
4           | rttrytrytyu |    1002
5           | qweqwret    |    1003
6           | gvcbvcbcv   |    1003

SELECT 
    PRIMARY_KEY, 
    TEXT_FIELD, 
    SERIES_ID
FROM MY_TABLE 
OFFSET 0 
FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY;
```

What I'd like to do is to change my SQL statement so that instead of fetching the next X amount of rows it will fetch the next X amount of SERIES_IDs from the table.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should always use `ORDER BY` with `FETCH FIRST`.  SQL tables and result sets (with no `ORDER BY`) represent *unordered* sets.  So the results may not be stable.

Now, this doesn't do exactly what you are asking for, but it might do what you want.  Oracle supports the `WITH TIES` options for `FETCH NEXT`.  This would let you get all the data for the last series id:

```
SELECT PRIMARY_KEY, TEXT_FIELD, SERIES_ID
FROM MY_TABLE 
ORDER BY SERIES_ID
OFFSET 0 FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY WITH TIES;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use an analytic function (e.g. `DENSE_RANK()`) to label the series values with a number and then use that in the where clause, something along the lines of:

```
SELECT primary_key,
       text_field,
       series_id
FROM   (SELECT primary_key,
               text_field,
               series_id,
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY series_id) dr
        FROM   my_table)
WHERE  dr <= 3;
```

It does not look like it's possible to access values in the OFFSET/FETCH, so you'll have to use the dense_rank to do the pagination.